# Time complexity to remove an item from the heap

Tags: data-structures, heaps, heap-sort

Given an array of size $n$ that has the item of the heap. To remove an arbitrary element from the heap we would need $O(n)$ to find the element and then $O(logn)$ to reheapify if I am commrect, which means total time complexity is $O(n + logn)=O(n)$. In study notes, I saw it's written $O(nlogn)$, which does not make sense to me as both finding and reheapify are separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. O(n) to find an arbitrary item, O(log n) to remove it, total O(n).

If you often remove arbitrary items, say you insert n items, then remove the largest or a random item each n/2 times, then the total will be quite large. In this case you could consider a different approach: Mark items as “removed” that you want to remove, then you remove those marked items whenever you encounter them while adding an item or removing the largest item.